# setbkcolor() ineffective in Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

Tags: c, bgi

I recently started using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 to experiment with graphics program in C(thanks to this [tutorial](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/)). But for some reason [setbkcolor()](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/setbkcolor.html) does absolutely nothing. Here's the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    initwindow(800,600);
    setbkcolor(GREEN);   //FAILED. also tried "setbkcolor(2);"
    while ( !kbhit() ){}
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the Output: [image: black colored screen still]

I am using **Windows 7 Professional**. Is this something to do with the Operating System?

Comment: Are you sure that the correct flags during compilation? Also, what do you mean *"it does not seem to work"*?

Comment: It compiles fine. I meant to say that its ineffective. Edited.

Comment: the link to setbgcolor() says: "Also, only future drawing will use the new background color"  This means set the background color BEFORE doing any drawing, not after the object (in this case the whole window) is already drawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/setbkcolor.html) says in the *Windows notes* part:

> Also, only future drawing will use the new background color (anything currently drawn in the old background color will stay in the old color). Calling `setbkcolor(0)` will change the background color to the current color at index `[0]` of the palette (rather than always changing the background to black).

You have misunderstood the goal of the function.

Comment: Yup, you're right....using `circle(200, 200, 150);` doesn't changes anything(as it uses the old background color) but `outtextxy()` after `setbkcolor()` does produces the output string enclosed in a box of the new background color. Unfortunately its not what I wanted, any other way you think I can change the background color?

Comment: A hacky solution would be drawing a screen-sized filled rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

since the window is drawn before even setting the background color.
use cleardevice() after setting the background color to recreate the screen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>

int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
    setbkcolor(GREEN);
    cleardevice();

    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```